# Can we create std::istringstream object from a reversed std::string

Tags: c++, c++14, c++20, stdstring, istringstream

I am learning C++ using [recommended C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, i read about `std::istringstream` and saw the following example:

```
std::string s("some string");
std::istringstream ss(s);
std::string word;
while(ss >> word)
{
    std::cout<<word <<" ";
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
some string
```

**Desired Output**

```
string some
```

My question is that how can we create the above `std::istringstream` object `ss` using the reversed string(that contains the word in the reverse order as shown in the desired output)? I looked at [std::istringstream's](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/) constructors but couldn't find one that takes iterators so that i can pass `str.back()` and `str.begin()` instead of passing a `std::string`.

Comment: Put the string into an input stringstream and read word by word from the stream (like you do now) but push the words into a *stack*. Then in a second loop pop from the stack and print the words.

Comment: "*couldn't find one that takes iterators*" It wouldn't matter if they did; iterators are based on *characters* not words. Reverse iterators would iterate backwards by character.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes i am aware of that. I was just giving an example to show that at least there should be a constructor that takes iterators. I know that even if we use those iterators we will iterate backwards character by character instead of word by word. Thanks anyways for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: It may be obvious to you but Nicol had no way of knowing that and they were just trying to help. If you don't want people to try and help you then I'm not sure why you've asked a question?

Comment: @Sean: "*I was just giving an example to show that at least there should be a constructor that takes iterators.*" But that wouldn't help, because there aren't iterators that spit out characters in reverse-word order. I mean, you could in theory write one, but it would probably be more efficient to just create a new string in reverse-word order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass iterators to the `istringstream` constructor indirectly if you use a temporary string:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s{"Hello World\n"};
    std::istringstream ss({s.rbegin(),s.rend()});
    std::string word;
    while(ss >> word)
    {
        std::cout<<word <<" ";
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/PPG88EjPb):

```
dlroW olleH
```

Though thats reversing the string, not words. If you want to print words in reverse order a `istringstream` alone does not help much. You can use some container to store the extracted words and then print them in reverse:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string s{"Hello World\n"};
    std::istringstream ss(s);
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    while(ss >> word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    for (auto it = words.rbegin(); it != words.rend(); ++it) std::cout << *it << " ";
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/xeh1Td889):

```
World Hello
```

Comment: `You can pass iterators to the istringstream constructor.` your example uses temporary variable of type `std::string`. So this iterators are not passed to `std::istringstream`, but to `std::string`.

Comment: @MarekR fixed the wording

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the `c++20` tag:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string s("some string");
    std::string word;
    std::istringstream ss(s);

    while(ss >> word)
    {
        vec.push_back(word);
    }

    for (auto v : vec | std::views::reverse)
    {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
}
```